# How to access nth element through CSS in IE6+7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to know how we can access n<sup>th</sup> element of an `<li>` using CSS in IE6/IE7.

HTML:

```
<ul class="myUL">
  <li><a href="" target="">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now suppose I want to access Link2, how to do that?
Note: Without using javascript.Only through CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Give it a unique class name.

You can do `:first` and `:last` but not n'th and I'm not sure they work in IE6 either.

```
<ul class="myUL">
  <li class="link1"><a href="" target="">Link1</a></li>
  <li class="link2"><a href="">Link2</a></li>
  <li class="link3"><a href="">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in CSS, reference `ul.myUl li.link2`

Answer (score 3):

As Ian corretly stated, can't do that with static CSS. You could however use JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<ul class="myUL" id="myUL">
    <li><a href="" target="">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var n = 2;
nthElem = getElementById("myUL").childNodes[n-1];
nthElem.style = "color: red";
//or
nthElem.className = "cssClassForNthElem";
```

Comment: thnx for ur help, but i have mentioned "without javascript" ,
any other alternate way?

Comment: Somu: yeah, I see you've added that. Sorry, only alternatives are that one or the Ian's .

Answer (score 1):

Just like Ian says, this is impossible in IE6 and AFAIK in IE7 as well.  IE7 and IE8 actually support the `:first-child` selector from CSS 2.1 (I'm sure you can guess what that does), but not `:nth-child` nor `:last-child` which are CSS 3.